# Block z axis when using Quaternion.AngleAxis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, touch, quaternions, 360-panorama

I'm creating a 360 viewer and I want to alternate between gyroscope and touch. I have all working but want to improve the touch control where I'm a bit stuck. I'm using this code :

```
    float x = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x;
                    float y = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y;
                    float speed2 = 0.09f;

                    this.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(x*speed2, Vector3.up);
                    this.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(y*speed2, Vector3.left);
```

It works perfect but I want to block the z axis for prevent weird views when you move your finger making diagonals or when try to rotate 180º. I tried some codes but have no luck.

Thanks so much!